# $X,Y,Z$ are iid random variables $\implies$ $X-Y$ are $Y-Z$ are independent

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X,Y,Z$ be independently and identically distributed random variables. Is it true in general that $X-Y$ and $Y-Z$ are independent$?$ Is there any counter example$?$

Comment: Suppose that $X, Y, Z$ are independent and that $X-Y$ and $Y-Z$ are independent. These two conditions necessarily imply that $Y$ is a constant random variable. This can be easily read out from Robert Israel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true.  Any nontrivial example you try will be a counterexample, because
$\text{Cov}(X-Y, Y-Z) = - \text{Var}(Y)$.